What do we know about the Poisson boundary of arbitrary Riemannian manifolds?
For closed manifolds, we know that the Poisson boundary is trivial due to compactness and for radially symmetric manifolds for which diffusion is one dimensional, there are A Brief Introduction to Brownian motion on a Riemannian Manifold by Elton P Hsu  and Kinetic Brownian motion on Riemannian manifolds by Angst, Ballieul and Tardif which made me wonder if the only Riemannian manifolds which admit one-dimensional diffusions are the radially symmetric ones. Furthermore, what do we know about Poisson boundaries in the general setting.
